# Alternative to current loop structure

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the quantiles for a large dataset in R. My code currently looks like this:

```
percentile <- numeric(length=5000000)

for (i in 1:5000000){
percentile[i] <- quantile(Result[1:i],0.1)
}
```

Where `Result` is a vector of 5 million observations. It is important that the quantile is calculated based on the number of observations to date, as I'm testing simulation convergence. Currently this code takes an extremely long time to run, making it unusable. Is there a quicker way to do this, using vectorisation or some function in the plyr package? I've already tried the foreach package and although slightly faster, this still takes a massive amount of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating much more quantiles than relevant. The code below should do

```
percentile <- sapply(
    seq(1000, 5000000, by = 1000),
    function(i){
        quantile(head(Result, i), 0.1)
    }
)
```